# local lan server

Tags: lan

i am facing a issue, i have installed ubuntu 17 version and in my computer which act like a local lan server. I am having two lan card one is connected to my DSL router for internet and another one is a ethernet connected to switch.

Second ethernet port actually shares the net. I know how to do this in windows but i am having a confusion.

In this local server i am having two ethernet port, one is inbuild and another one is link to switch.

i am looking for any suggestion regarding this.

configuration are as follows:

1. ethernet port connected to internet router

automatic DHCP selected

2. ethernet connected to switch

ip address : 192.168.0.1
subnet : 255.255.255.0
no gateway or gateway : 192.168.1.1

if i am pinging both ethernet ip from any node then its working fine. But from local server i cant ping any node.(for instance 192.168.0.18)

Saju